# Samsung Galaxy SHV-160k won't get signal

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, network-signal

I bought on ebay a refurbish Galaxy Note N-7000. Once I received it I put my chip and for my surprise there was no signal. After checking It I noticed it has on the back of the phone N-7000 but when I see on the software it says SHV-160K.

Right now, I don't know what else to do with this phone because it simply doesn't recognize any network, it just displays a `NO SyMBOL` where it should display the carrier signal bars.

I'm posting to see if there is any way this phone can be use or IF I should ditch it.

This is what It lists on the about device page

Model: SHV-E160K

Android Version: 4.1.2

Band Base: E160KKKJLL6

Kernel version: 3.0.31 - 10034927
se.infra@SEP-93 #1
SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 22 12:43:28 KST 2013

Compilation: JZO54K.E160KKKJMC3

Answer (score 0):

The SHV-160K is a version of the phone only made for the South Korean market. It works in the US, but only on GSM, not 3G or LTE, because the US cell networks use different frequencies to South Korea. (The Western half of S America uses the same frequencies as the US.)

This tells me that it should work as a 2G phone for you, but perhaps there's no GSM coverage where you are, only LTE? In that case, you're screwed and you should sell your phone to a Korean on eBay.